How to pass specific parameters to vts-tradefed?
I am looking for options for passing specific parameters to vts-tradefed to achieve the following use case.
Need to execute the full set of VTS Tests, while some of the test suites require an argument to adjust to the specifics of the target hardware.
Is there a way to pass arguments to vts-tradefed, e.g. something like the following or are there any equivalent options?
vts-tradefd run commandAndExt vts type=1

The argument type=1 shall be passed to the test suites where it will be interpreted at test runtime.
I studied the documentation for Tradefed but could not find anything that would do the job.
